# seekToCurrentErrorHandler fails in case there are multiple failed records from different partitions if FixedBackOff is set as FixedBackOff(0L, 1)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

With spring-kafka-2.5.4.RELEASE version, when there are multiple failed records from different partitions, seekToCurrentErrorHandler fails if FixedBackOff is set with maxAttempts as 1 and interval other than -1L.

SeekToCurrentErrorHandler seekToCurrentErrorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(,new FixedBackOff(0L, 1));

Although setting a value for interval other than -1L doesn't make sense when the maxAttemps count is 1 (as there will be no retry and hence no retry interval), shouldn't it either fail at startup complaining same or should be handled appropriately?.
It fails at run time when there are multiple failed records from different partitions with below error.

ERROR org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Error handler threw an exception
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: <some IO Exception here, not one of them defined in FailedRecordProcessor.configureDefaultClassifier()>
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:157)

This seems to be with the below line.

Line 96 of FailedRecordTracker(i.e. if (nextBackOff != BackOffExecution.STOP) { )

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/v2.5.4.RELEASE/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/FailedRecordTracker.java#L96

which subsequently is resulting in entry to line 157 of SeekUtils(i.e. throw new KafkaException("Seek to current after exception", level, thrownException);)

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/v2.5.4.RELEASE/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/SeekUtils.java#L157

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are migrating from an older version.

`maxAttempts` in `FixedBackOff` means max **retry** attempts so should be 0 for no retries.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#seek-to-current

> Starting with version 2.3, a `BackOff` can be provided to the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` and `DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor` so that the consumer thread can sleep for some configurable time between delivery attempts. Spring Framework provides two out of the box `BackOff` s, `FixedBackOff` and `ExponentialBackOff`. The maximum back off time must not exceed the `max.poll.interval.ms` consumer property, to avoid a rebalance.

> **IMPORTANT:** Previously, the configuration was "maxFailures" (which included the first delivery attempt). When using a `FixedBackOff`, its `maxAttempts` property represents the number of delivery retries (one less than the old `maxFailures` property). Also, `maxFailures=-1` meant retry indefinitely with the old configuration, with a BackOff you would set the `maxAttempts` to `Long.MAX_VALUE` for a `FixedBackOff` and leave the `maxElapsedTime` to its default in an ExponentialBackOff.